# Insert n amount of values to an empty doubly linked list (pseudocode)

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

Can someone help me verify if my pseudocode works correctly so the function presented appends n numbers to a list?

I need help with an assignment on my first year on data-science.

We are learning about data structures and about doubly linked lists. 
I understand the logic behind doubly linked list I think, but the I have a hard time writing what's happening in pseudocode.

> **"Assignment 1: Let the list S be empty as a start. Now input n (natural numbers, e.g.: 1, 2, 3 ...) one at the time.
>   When the last number of n is placed into the list,
>   the list will be a sorted list containing the n 
>   numbers.
>   Describe why we'll get a sorted n number in O(n^2) time."**

My answer to the assignment is written below, and I am really unsure if it's correct.

```
// Our nodes will consist of 3 cells in each object.
// key  = a number (int)
// prev = address pointer to previous node 
// next = address pointer til next node

// This function creates an empty list
function emptyList()
   L = new List{head = nil, size = 0}
   return L

// This function creates a node.
function makeNode(val)
  node = new Node{prev = NIL, key = val, next = NIL}
  return node

// This function inserts n amount of nodes to an empty list
function InsertNodes(n)

    // Create an empty list, S.
    emptyList()

    // Initiate the first node
    S.head  = makeNode(1) 

    for i = 2 to n-1

        prevNode = makeNode(i-1)
        newNode  = makeNode(i)

        while newNode.prev == NIL do

            // connect addresses of nodes
            prevNode.next = newNode.prev
            newNode.prev  = prevNode.next
```

The course is about algorithms and discrete mathematics

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Until you have a known problem with your program, you do not yet have a valid Stack Overflow question.

Comment: But, the question is not about coding, right? And the question is confusing? Because we can sort any list O(nlogn) time. does the question says, keep the list sorted while inserting new elements?

Comment: The question is if my pseudocode is correct. Is my pseudocode correct? I want it to answer the assignment presented so it appends n amount of values to a doubly linked list. Im just not sure what I am doing is correct as I am currently learning about linked lists for the first time I'd be glad if someone more experienced than me could have a look. 

The topic is about algorithms and doubly linked lists so it sure is about coding.

Comment: i = 2 to n-1, should be n

Comment: Thanks Kelalaka!

Comment: By the way using addToHead with number counting down will be more clean code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Our nodes will consist of 3 cells in each object.
// key  = a number (int)
// prev = address pointer to previous node 
// next = address pointer til next node

// This function creates an empty list
function emptyList()
   L = new List{head = nil, size = 0}
   return L

// This function creates a node.
function makeNode(val)
  node = new Node{prev = NIL, key = val, next = NIL}
  return node

// This function inserts n amount of nodes to an empty list
function InsertNodes(n)

    // Create an empty list, S.
    emptyList()

    // Initiate the first node
    S.head  = makeNode(1) 

    //tail keeps the last node
    tail = head
    for i = 2 to n

        tail.next = makeNode(i)
        tail.next.prev = tail
        tail = tail.next
```

Comment: Thanks Kelalaka! <3